# Animation of multiple text elements in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I feel like this isn't the most effective nor efficient way of doing things:

```
line.stop(true, true).show('slide', {direction: whichway}, speed-150, function() {
  title.stop(true, true).fadeIn(speed-200, function() {
    sub.stop(true, true).show('slide', {direction: whichway}, speed-50, function() {
      subtext.stop(true, true).show();
      paragraph.stop(true, true).slideDown(speed);
    });
  });
});
```

whichway/speed are dynamic, but other than that it's all stuff that has to be in sync and queued up.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Apart from indentation/Style I don't think there is any other option short of putting it in your own queue ... and that would seem like overkill for this. Are you looking for style/readability recommendations?

Comment: Is this code called more than once? If yes, you should be aware that you are re-creating the 3 callback functions whenever the code is called. Saving the functions into variables and delivering these variables as parameters would fix this; using when, as @LarryBattle suggested, also fixes this.

Answer (score 2):

For readability, take advantage of jQuery methods that use the jQuery [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to eliminate your deeply nested callback structure.
Example [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) can turn your code into this.

```
$.when({}).then(function(){
    return line.stop(true, true).show('slide', {direction: whichway}, speed-150);
}).then(function() {
    return title.stop(true, true).fadeIn(speed-200);
}).then(function() {
    return sub.stop(true, true).show('slide', {direction: whichway}, speed-50 );
}).then(function() {
    subtext.stop(true, true).show();
    return paragraph.stop(true, true).slideDown(speed);
});
```

Here's another example of using $.when: http://jsfiddle.net/Tp569/

Code from demo.

CSS:

```
.box{
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box1" class="box">Box 1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">Box 2</div>
```

JS:

```
$.when({}).then(function(){
    return $("#box1").css("backgroundColor", "blue" )
        .fadeIn( "slow" ).delay(500).animate({
            opacity: 0.5,
            margin: '50'
        }, "slow").delay(1000);
}).then(function() {
    return $("#box2").css("backgroundColor", "yellow" ).fadeIn( "fast" );
});
```

For speed, try out [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/), which is a pure css 3 base animation library.
If that's not enough then [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596429/jquery-best-practice-for-speeding-up-animation)